# Pandas strange column that makes my tests fail - how can I drop this column?

Tags: pandas

The code -

```
    df: pd.DataFrame = kwargs['df']
    max_bin = 6
    bins = [x for x in range(0, max_bin + 1)]

    df['new_inf_day'] = df['day']
    df.loc[~df['name'].isin(['A', 'B']), 'new_inf_day'] = max_bin + 1

    ans = df.groupby(['id', pd.cut(df['new_inf_day'], bins=bins)]).size().unstack()

    new_name = {}
    for old_col, index in zip(ans.columns.tolist(), bins[1:]):
        new_name[old_col] = f'name_{index - 1}_to_{index}'

    ans.rename(columns=new_name, inplace=True)
    return ans.reset_index('id')
```

The results are fine and I don't see the column `new_inf_day` in the results DataFrame when I print it on the screen, but despite this the unit tests keep to fail and I see there is is a mention of this column in the debug window -

[image]

What is this column and how can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a column, this is the column's **axis name**.

You can remove it with [`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
ans = ans.rename_axis(columns=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was -
`ans.columns.name = None`